# SSRS Ratio is matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created the following Matrix in SSRS:

```
                  [Account]           Total
Deposits          [Sum(Deposit)]      [Sum(Deposit)]
Withdrawals       [Sum(Withdrawals)]  [Sum(Withdrawals)]
Withdrawal Ratio  ??????????          =Sum(Fields!Withdrawals.Value, "DataSet1")/Sum(Fields!Deposit.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Example:

```
                  Account A.......Account B        Total
Deposits          75..............25...............100
Withdrawals       10..............25...............35
Withdrawal Ratio  13%.............100%.............35%
```

Source data:

```
Date........Account.....Deposits.....Withdrawals
2013/08/01..A...............20................2
2013/08/02..A...............20................2
2013/08/03..A...............20................2
2013/08/04..A...............15................4
2013/08/01..B...............10................8
2013/08/02..B...............15................17
```

The [Account] column is a group. Currently we have 2 different types of Accounts.
I'm trying to calculate the withdrawal ratio (Withdrawals/Deposits).
It works for the total.
But I can't get it to work for the individual groups. It displays the ratio for the combined accounts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add some example data and the expected results? It's a lot easier to see the requirements that way.

Comment: Hi @IanPreston, I added the required results, and the source data I'm basing it on. (Basically, I have sum of deposits and withdrawals for each account for each day over a period of time. I want to summarise deposits and withdrawals per account, and calculate the withdrawal to deposit ratio.) Thanks! Errol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this natively in SSRS.

I've used your data:

[image]

And created a Tablix:

[image]

I based this off a Matrix initially, but removed the row group - you can see that only grouping is the `Account` column.

The **Withdrawal Ratio** expression is just:

```
=Sum(Fields!Withdrawals.Value) / Sum(Fields!Deposits.Value)
```

Compared to your example I'm not specifying a scope for the aggregate - since this gets executed in both the column scope (i.e. Account) and the total scope this will give the required results in each section:

[image]

Once the grouping for the Tablix is set up correctly everything else should follow.

Comment: That works! Thank you! I'm sure I tried that last week. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, @user2708232! If an answer works for you, please consider setting it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.